# How do I pull out the string in argv position 1 in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say I run the program in the command line as

```
./program mom cat dad
```

`argv[1]` is equal to "mom"

How do I get the array of characters in `argv[1]` to put them individually into a linked list ?

Comment: Do you have any code you tried, something to build an answer upon ?

Comment: Could you show the linked list structure you want to put them into?

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` is the array you are looking for. That means `argv[1][0]` is the first character, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are always just `char` arrays, so `argv[1]` is already an array of characters.  For example, you could do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
    printf("Character %d = %c\n", i, argv[1][i]);
}
```

There are already plenty of resources on implementing linked lists in C (e.g: [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html)), so I suggest you use this information to give it a go and come back if you're stuck with that.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already here, it's worth mentioning that you would generally copy strings into your list.  You can use `strdup` (defined in `string.h`) to copy a string.  For example:

```
listnode->value = strdup(argv[1]);
```

That means your list now owns a little slice of memory containing that copied string, so it's responsible for calling `free` on that pointer when the list node is freed.

However, I ought to mention that you are allowed to modify the arguments array.  So if your list is only operating on the supplied arguments you don't necessarily need to copy them (unless you want to reallocate the memory), even if you plan to modify the string data.

If you are just storing a single character value in each list node, there's no such requirement.  You would simply have a list structure like this:

```
struct node {
    char value;
    struct node *next;
};
```